# Memory channel tangle: Clean up [single-channel], [dual-channel], [triple-channel], and [multi-channel]

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

There's a bunch of different tags related to [multi-channel memory architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture), including [single-channel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/single-channel), [dual-channel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dual-channel), and [triple-channel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/triple-channel). However, we happen to have [multi-channel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-channel) as well.

Can someone get rid of this "channel tangle" and consolidate all these tags into [multi-channel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-channel)?

---

The [multi-channel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-channel) is actually ambiguous as it can also refer to multi-channel audio. Perhaps it should be split into [multi-channel-memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-channel-memory) and [multichannel-audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multichannel-audio)? The above tags can then be merged into [multi-channel-memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-channel-memory).

---

Maybe we should just clean up all these tags instead? I have to agree with @OliverSalzburg that they aren't all that useful.

Comment: that multi-channel tag also refers to Multichannel audio

Answer (score 4):

[single-channel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/single-channel) is not [multi-channel](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/multi-channel), so merging either into the other wouldn't make sense.

That being said, I think all of these tags are worthless. [memory](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/memory) and [audio](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/audio) are sufficient.

Comment: You mean "memory-ram" and "audio-card"? Because, memory and audio are using to much more than what you think.

Comment: @Braiam: Those are the tags we have right now. I don't think introducing new tags is a good idea here. If you think `[audio]` and `[memory]` should be split up or otherwise cleaned up, please suggest it in a new question.